# using variables in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps-api-3

From the google maps API documentation I have got this working:

```
var flightPlanCoordinates = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.772323, -122.214897),
    new google.maps.LatLng(21.291982, -157.821856),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-18.142599, 178.431),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-27.46758, 153.027892)
  ];
```

what ive tried to do is replicate this piece of code with my own loop so I can use previously stored co-ords, like so:

```
var output;
$.getJSON('DisplayMap.php',  function(data) {
        var output = "[ ";
        for (var i in data.b) {
            output+= "new google.maps.LatLng" + "(" + data.b[i].Ya + ", " + data.b[i].Za + ")," + " ";
        }

       output+= "]";
        document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=output;
    alert(output);
  });


                output+= "]";
```

Ive checked the output and it looks exactly as I want it to. however, when I substitute it in like this is doesnt work:

```
var flightPlanCoordinates = output;
```

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your new code you are building a string instead of an array.  You should have something like this instead:

```
var output = [];

for (var i in data.b) {
    output.push(new google.maps.LatLng(data.b[i].Ya, data.b[i].Za));
}
```

In addition, I am slightly confused by the fact that you create a variable named `output` both inside and outside of `getJSON`.  Keep in mind that `getJSON` is asynchronous and you will not be able to use the variable from within `getJSON` immediately after it is called.

Comment: thanks both. So now I have the code you've provided how would I layout the var flightPlanCoordinates = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.772323, -122.214897),
    new google.maps.LatLng(21.291982, -157.821856),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-18.142599, 178.431),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-27.46758, 153.027892)
  ];

Comment: i got it. GET int there. Cheers folks

Answer (score 2):

You have to set up a correct javascript `Array` instead of a string. Like this:

```
var output = [];
$.getJSON('DisplayMap.php',  function(data) {
        for (var i in data.b) {
            output.push(new google.maps.LatLng(data.b[i].Ya, data.b[i].Za));
        }
  });
```